# Override a method in Java generically

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-conversion, overriding

If I have a base class like this that I can't change:

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract Object get(int i);
}
```

and I try to extend it with a class `B` like this:

```
public class B extends A{
    @Override
    public String get(int i){
        //impl
        return "SomeString";
    }
}
```

everything is OK. But my attempt to make it more generic fails if I try:

```
public class C extends A{
    @Override
    public <T extends Object> T get(int i){
        //impl
        return (T)someObj;
    }
}
```

I can't think of any reason why this should be disallowed. In my understanding, the generic type `T` is bound to an `Object`—which is the requested return type of `A`. If I can put `String` or `AnyObject` as my return type inside `B`, why am I not allowed to put `<T extends Object> T` inside my `C` class?

Another strange behavior, from my point of view, is that an additional method like this:

```
public class D extends A{

    @Override
    public Object get(int i){
        //impl
    }

    public <T extends Object> T get(int i){
        //impl
    }
}
```

is also not allowed, with the hint of a `DuplicateMethod` provided. This one, at least, confuses me, and I think Java should make a decision: if it is the ***same*** return type, why not allow overriding; and if it is not, why shouldn't I be able to add this method? To tell me it's the same, but not allow it to be overridden, is very weird, based on common sense.

Comment: For your first case, what error/warning to you get?

Comment: @wulfgar.pro The method get(int) of type C must override or implement a supertype method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[JLS # 8.4.2. Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
> - m2 has the same signature as m1, or
> - the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the
>     signature of m2.

**As per above rule as your parent do not have an erasure and your child has one so it is not a valid overriding.**

[JLS#8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)

**Example 8.4.8.3-4. Erasure Affects Overriding**

A class cannot have two member methods with the same name and type erasure:

```
class C<T> {
    T id (T x) {...}
}
class D extends C<String> {
    Object id(Object x) {...}
}
```

This is illegal since D.id(Object) is a member of D, C.id(String) is declared in a supertype of D, and:

- The two methods have the same name, id
- C.id(String) is accessible to D
- The signature of D.id(Object) is not a subsignature of that of
  C.id(String)
- The two methods have the same erasure

Two different methods of a class may not override methods with the same erasure:

```
 class C<T> {
     T id(T x) {...}
 }
 interface I<T> {
     T id(T x);
 }
 class D extends C<String> implements I<Integer> {
    public String  id(String x)  {...}
    public Integer id(Integer x) {...}
 }
```

This is also illegal, since D.id(String) is a member of D, D.id(Integer) is declared in D, and:

- The two methods have the same name, id
- D.id(Integer) is accessible to D
- The two methods have different signatures (and neither is a
  subsignature of the other)
- D.id(String) overrides C.id(String) and D.id(Integer)
  overrides I.id(Integer) yet the two overridden methods have the same
  erasure

Also It gives example of a case where it is allowed from super to child

> The notion of subsignature is designed to express a relationship between two methods whose signatures are not identical, but in which one may override the other. Specifically, it allows a method whose signature does not use generic types to override any generified version of that method. This is important so that library designers may freely generify methods independently of clients that define subclasses or subinterfaces of the library.

Consider the example:

```
class CollectionConverter {
List toList(Collection c) {...}
}
class Overrider extends CollectionConverter {
 List toList(Collection c) {...}
```

}

Now, assume this code was written before the introduction of generics, and now the author of class CollectionConverter decides to generify the code, thus:

```
 class CollectionConverter {
   <T> List<T> toList(Collection<T> c) {...}
 }
```

**Without special dispensation, Overrider.toList would no longer override CollectionConverter.toList. Instead, the code would be illegal.** This would significantly inhibit the use of generics, since library writers would hesitate to migrate existing code.

Comment: I understand tgat this may be a problem. However I see it as a Problem if the _BASE_ class is going to change. Here I want the Superclass to change the return type. If in the Future `A` changes to String get(int i) any othe child of it gets broken, too

Comment: @LukasEder Added That specific case.

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't get it. In your examples a GENERIC method gets overriden by a concrete Type. In my case, I want Object to get Overriden by a Generic Type, which is bound to - of course - Object. Generally, if a return Type of `Object` is requested, i should be able to override it with ANY Type which is NOT a Raw Type.

Comment: Because your parent class does not have erasure and your child class has one. As stated in the sub-signature rule above it is not a valid overriding.

Comment: I realize this is a 4 year old question. But your erasure comment is wrong, @AmitDeshpande. Compiling @RafaelT's code gets you... 

`...error: name clash: <T>get(int) in C and get(int) in A have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other...`

Nor is the problem the signatures.  `A.get(int i)` and `C.get(int i)` both are indeed subsignatures of each other. 

The simplest solution is `public class C <T> extends A` ... `public <T> void getI(int i)`. It would be redundant to do `<T extends Object>` because just declaring the `<T>` on its own is shorthand for `<T extends Object>`

Answer (score 5):

Well, for the first part, the answer would be that Java does not allow non-generic methods to be overridden by generic methods, even if the erasure is the same. It means that it wouldn't work even if you would just have the overriding method as:

```
 public <T extends Object> Object get(int i)
```

I don't know why Java poses this limitation (gave it some thought), I just think it has to do with special cases implemented for sub-classing generic types.

Your second definition would essentially translate to:

```
public class D extends A{

    @Override
    public Object get(int i){
    //impl
    }

    public Object get(int i){
        //impl
    }

}
```

which is obviously a problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the JLS section [8.4.8.3 Overriding and hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a type declaration T has a member method m1 and there exists a method m2 declared in T or a supertype of T such that **all of the following conditions hold**:
>
> 1. m1 and m2 have the same name.
> 2. m2 is accessible from T.
> 3. The signature of m1 is not a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
> 4. The signature of m1 or some method m1 overrides (directly or indirectly) has the same erasure as the signature of m2 or some method m2 overrides (directly or indirectly).

1 and 2 holds.

3 holds too because (quote from [JLS section 8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)):

> The notion of subsignature is designed to express a relationship between two methods whose signatures are not identical, but in which one may override the other. **Specifically, it allows a method whose signature does not use generic types to override any generified version of that method.**

And you are having the other way: a method with generic type overriding one without generic.

4 holds too because the erased signatures are the same: `public Object get(int i)`

Comment: Your «_3 holds too..._» comment is wrong, @dcernahoschi. 

`A.get(int i)` and `C.get(int i)` both are indeed subsignatures of each other. 

The OP's original code fails with:

 `...error: name clash: <T>get(int) in C and get(int) in A have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other...`

Change it to...

 `public class C <T> extends A` ... `public <T> void get(int i)`. 

...and it compiles fine.

That fact the above change to only the class declaration results in succesful compilation, means that the original signatures are indeed perfectly fine as subsignatures.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the following invocation.

```
A a = new C();
a.get(0);
```

In effect you are calling a generic method, yet you're not passing in any type arguments. As things stand, this is not much of a problem. Those type arguments disappear during code generation anyways. Yet reification has never been taken off the table and the stewards of Java the language have tried and [continue to try](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2010-July/001781.html) and keep that door open. If type arguments were reified, your invocation would not provide any to a method that requires one.

Answer (score 1):

@RafaelT's original code results in this compilation error...

---

```
C.java:3: error: C is not abstract and does not override abstract method get(int) in A
public class C extends A { 
       ^
C.java:5: error: name clash: <T>get(int) in C and get(int) in A have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    public  <T extends Object> T  get ( int i ){ 
                              ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>get(int)
```

---

The simplest, most straightfoward solution to get @RafaelT's C subclass to compile successfully, is...

---

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract Object get(int i);
}
```

---

```
public class C<T> extends A {
    @Override
    public T get(int i){
        //impl
        return (T)someObj;
    }
}
```

---

Although I'm sure other people meant well with their answers. Nevertheless, a few of the answers seem to have majorly misinterpreted [*the JLS*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2).

The above change to only the class declaration, results in a successful compilation. That fact alone, means that @RafaelT's original signatures are indeed perfectly fine [*as subsignatures*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) — *contrary to what others have suggested*.

I'm not going to make the same mistake that others who answered seem to have made, and try to pretend I fully grok the JLS generics documentation. I confess that I haven't figured out with 100% certainty, the root cause of the OP's original compilation failure.

But I suspect it has ***something*** to do with an unfortunate combination of the OP's use of `Object` as [*the return type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5) on top of the typical confusing and quirky subtleties of Java's generics.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [*erasure*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

In your example:

```
public class D extends A{

  @Override
  public Object get(int i){
      //impl
  }

  public <T extends Object> T get(int i){
      //impl
  }
}
```

The compiler generated byte code for your generic method will be identical to your non-generic method; that is, `T` will be replaced with the upper bound, that being `Object`. That's why you're getting the `DuplicateMethod` warning in your IDE.

Comment: I understand that it is the same Type. Thats why I'm wondering I'm not allowed to just Override it *WITH THE SAME TYPE*

Answer (score 0):

Declaring method as `<T extends Object> T get(int i)` makes no sense without declaring `T` somewhere else - in the method's arguments or in a field of the enclosing class. In the latter case, just parameterize the whole class with the type `T`.

Comment: It makes sense if you want to "unsafely" conveniently auto-cast objects to any T. As the compiler can infer types in assignments: `String s = get(0);` instead of `String s = (String) get(0);`

Answer (score 0):

There's a conceptual problem. Suppose `C#get()` overrides `A#get()`

```
A a = new C();
Object obj = a.get();  // actually calling C#get()
```

but `C#get()` requires a `T` - what should `T` be? There is no way to determine.

You can protest that `T` is not required due to erasure. That is correct today. However erasure was considered a "temporary" workaround. The type system in most part does not assume erasure; it is actually carefully designed so that it can be made fully "reifiable", i.e. without erasure, in future version of java without breaking existing code.

Comment: as mentioned in the answer above from Alexei and the comment below from @LukasEder: T should be the leftHand assignment argument to autocast Objects. In your case it just is bound to Object

Comment: heads will explode if we combine inference rules with override rules.