# Cannot override generic interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, overriding, abstract-class

I'm trying to create and interface of generic type methods, then implement them in a subclass and so on.  But I cannot figure out why my subclass throws an error that says I have not overridden the abstract method from my interface.  Code is as follows:

```
package stdmathops1;
public interface StdMathOps1<T>{
    public <T> T div(T f, T s);
    }
//this is all very simple and not the whole of it, at this point I'm just
//trying to figure out why it won't override the div method.
class Fraction implements StdMathOps1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
    public <T extends StdMathOps1> T div(T f, T s){
        return f;
    }
}
```

Wherever I look about overriding and using interfaces it seems right, but it still throws

```
Fraction is not abstract and does not override abstract method div(Object, Object)
in StdMathOps1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are adding a condition, changing your method so its not actually overriding. The method in your interface specifies any class type `<T>` while your attempt of overriding specifies a class type that must extend or fall under STDMathOps1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot override generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579153/override-a-method-in-java-generically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally can't change bounds on parameters like you did on overridden methods. To the compiler,

```
public <T> T div(T f, T s);
```

and

```
public <T extends StdMathOps1> T div(T f, T s);
```

are two different methods.

For more information, see [Cannot override generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579153/override-a-method-in-java-generically)

Comment: They don't have the same erasure.

Comment: You're right. My mistake, forgot that erasures on bounded types erase to the bounded type.