# Override error in java method with weird generics

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I am trying some weird generics in java.  In the following code, the override on `foo` works, but the override on `bar` doesn't.  I don't understand why.

Note that the only difference between the 2 overrides is in the constraints on `MB`.  When overriding `foo`, `MB` extends `Alpha<B, MB>` and it works.  When overriding `bar` `MB`, extends `Beta<B, MB>` and it does not work, even though `Beta<B, MB>` extends `Alpha<B, MB>`.

I would expect that `MB extends Beta<B, MB>` and `Beta<A, MA> extends Alpha<A, MA>` would imply `MB extends Alpha<B, MB>`.  So why doesn't it work?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

abstract class Alpha<A, MA extends Alpha<A, MA>> {
    abstract public <B, MB extends Alpha<B, MB>> MB foo(Function<A, B> f);
    abstract public <B, MB extends Alpha<B, MB>> MB bar(Function<A, B> f);
}

class Beta<A, MA extends Beta<A, MA>> extends Alpha<A, MA> {
    @Override public <B, MB extends Alpha<B, MB>> MB foo(Function<A, B> f) { return null; }
    @Override public <B, MB extends Beta<B, MB>> MB bar(Function<A, B> f) { return null; }
}
```

Comment: [Here's a simplified version](http://ideone.com/j9QkOG) of the same problem. When you override a generic method you can't change the bounds on the type parameters.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438813/cannot-override-generic-interface

Comment: OK people, I understand now.  In summary, you can't override a method while changing the bounds of a generic type.  Period.  This regardless of how you use the generic type and event whether you use it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the constraint `MB extends Beta<B, MB>` isn't the same as `MB extends Alpha<B, MB>`; so it's not overriding the `bar` method.

Like [the error message says](http://ideone.com/zU50BY):

```
Main.java:10: error: name clash: <B#1,MB#1>bar(Function<A#1,B#1>) in Beta and <B#2,MB#2>bar(Function<A#2,B#2>) in Alpha have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    @Override public <B, MB extends Beta<B, MB>> MB bar(Function<A, B> f) { return null; }
```

So, you need to change your generic constraints so that `Beta.bar` really does override `Alpha.bar`.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand it is not the same constraint.  But the constraint on MB in bar is more specific.  And it is used as the return type.  So, Beta.bar can not return any value that is not compatible with Alpha.bar.  So it should be ok.

Comment: OK, I accepted your answer as it is the closest to answering the question.  Maybe you should be clearer that it  doesn't matter how and whether the generic type is used.

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect that MB extends Beta<B, MB> and Beta<A, MA> extends Alpha<A, MA> would imply MB extends Alpha<B, MB>.

While the above statement is correct, all `MB` that extend `Beta<A, MB>` also extend `Alpha<A, MB>`, that's not the issue. The two method signatures

```
abstract public <B, MB extends Alpha<B, MB>> MB bar(Function<A, B> f);
```

and

```
public <B, MB extends Beta<B, MB>> MB bar(Function<A, B> f);
```

are in fact different! These methods will accept different arguments. Suppose I had a `class Gamma<A, MA extends Gamma<B, Gamma>> extends Alpha<A, MA>`. By the specification in your abstract class `Alpha`, `bar` could return an object of type `Gamma` because that is a subclass of `Alpha`. But in your "override" version of `bar` in `Beta` could not return a type of `Gamma` because `Gamma` is NOT a subclass of `Beta`. Therefore these two method signatures do in fact behave differently, making your override on bar invalid!

Comment: But Beta.bar has no obligation to return what Alpha.bar can.  So it shouldn't make the override invalid.  You can override a method with a new implementation that returns a more specific type.

Comment: I see your point. My guess would be that regardless of the generic argument only affecting the return argument, due to type erasure Java cannot allow the generic to be narrowed during override as it could affect other types that cannot be narrowed (ie arguments or something in the body of the function).

Comment: You have the right idea but it's not the return type that is problematic here. Covariant return types are fine in Java (see [e.g. here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1882587/2891664)). The issue is the type parameter declarations specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion.  I checked further and saw that even a difference on an unused generic parameter will make the override invalid.

Comment: @FlorianF makes sense, I think static type checking would be impossible otherwise?