# Type erasure return type conflict

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-erasure

Take the following example:

```
class A
{
}

class B extends A
{
}

class MyParent
{
    private A _a;

    public A getMyValue()
    {
        return _a;
    }
}

class MyChild extends MyParent
{
    @Override
    public B getMyValue()
    {
        return (B)super.getMyValue();
    }
}
```

How come the previous is valid but the following is not:

```
class MyChild extends MyParent
{
    @Override
    public <T extends B> T getMyValue()
    {
        return (T)super.getMyValue();
    }
}
```

I would think that since `T` extends `B` it wouldn't cause conflict with the parent `getMyValue()` implementation due to type erasure; however, it seems that this is not the case. I get an error saying that they both have the same erasure.

To clarify as to why I don't think they should conflict: `T extends B` should always be at least `B` or any child class thereof. `B` inherits from `A` and therefore is assignable to type `A`.

Could someone break this down for me and is there any way around this that does not require changing either the `A` class or `MyParent` class (per my requirements)?

---

Looking at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html it states that the erasure that my example should resolve to is `B`, not `A` further confusing me.

Additionally, if I change the `MyChild` class to the following:

```
class MyChild<T extends B> extends MyParent
{
    @Override
    public T getMyValue()
    {
        return (T)super.getMyValue();
    }
}
```

It works!

Is there some difference in how erasure is resolved at the method vs class level?

Comment: Slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12579153/1743880. Different in the regard that it actually works if the type bound is placed on the class rather than on the method.

Comment: Thank you, @Tunaki. Additionally, it's different in the regard that the generic upper bound is a child class of the overridden return type as opposed to the parent class, itself.