# Overriding methods with generic return types

Tags: java, generics

I do not understand this completely. Let's say I have this simple hierarchy:

```
class Animal { }
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
...
```

And this abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
  abstract <T extends Animal> T createFromList(List<Object> cells);
  abstract <T extends Animal> T createFromObj(Object cells);
}
```

And a subclass derived from it:

```
class SubClass extends AbstractClass {}
```

Within the derived class `SubClass` I'm allowed to override `createFromObj` like shown below. We will result in a warning but the class will still compile:

```
  @Override
  Dog createFromObj(Object cells) {...}
```

I understand that. The same is not true if I override the other method:

```
  @Override
  Dog createFromList(List<Object> cells) {...}
```

This will lead to a compilation error:

```
'createFromList(List<Object>)' in 'SubClass' clashes with 'createFromList(List<Object>)' in 'AbstractClass'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
```

Override details - [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

Okay, but what puzzles me is that this will compile:

```
  @Override
  <T extends Animal> T createFromList(List<Object> cells) {...}
```

The raw type will also compile (with a warning):

```
  @Override
  Dog createFromList(List cells) {...}
```

Why when the return type is `Dog` the method with the raw type compiles (with a warning) and the method with `List<Object>` won't and in the same time it will compile if the return type is `T`?

Comment: This post contains some related materials 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579153/override-a-method-in-java-generically

Comment: You should make `AbstractClass` generic, not its individual methods.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Agree, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: Which is why it is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A whole chain of events are going wrong here.

Your key problem is that `abstract <T extends Animal> T createFromList(List<Object> cells);` is useless bordering on the 'necessarily buggy' terrain. Just because javac will compile it, doesn't mean it's sensible. It's at the `public int add(int a, int b) { return a - b; }` level - compiles, but, meaningless. Your question is therefore more or less irrelevant. Yes, there are answers to your questions. They are esoteric and weird. They are not the kind of knowledge that is useful at all when writing java code. Because the *cause* of your questions is some nonsense code. The right fix is to get rid of the nonsense and then your questions have become moot.

#### But first, context

The answer to your question isn't going to make sense unless you understand what generics *mean*. SO answers are ordinarily meant to assume all knowledge not explicitly stated in the question, but if you knew what it meant, you'd know the `AbstractClass` definition is nonsense which would make this a weird question. Hence, I'm assuming you don't understand the semantics that underlie generics.

When you write:

```
public <T extends Animal> T foo() {}
```

You're saying that, for each and every invocation of the `foo` method, the **caller** picks some type T. And you **have no idea** what T is. It could be anything. Your code needs to be written such that it is sensible and violates no typing rules **for every possible choice the caller could ever make**.

In other words, putting it in very slightly more familiar terms, if you have a method: `public void foo(List<? extends Animal> list)`, that is often interpreted to mean: "Foo takes as argument a list of animals. Animal, Dog, Cat, they all extend Animal, all are fine". **But that is wrong**. The question mark is the hint: It actually means: "Foo takes as argument a list of.. I don't actually know. It's question mark. However, I do know one thing: Whatever it actually is, it's a list of some UNKNOWN subtype of Animal. It could be a list of cats. It could be a list of dogs. It could be a list of animals. I do not know. The code must be sensible and make no type violations **regardless** of what that list actually ends up being.

And that's why you **cannot** `.add()` to such a list. Try it!

```
List<? extends Animal> foo = new ArrayList<>();
foo.add(new Dog()); // error
foo.add(new Cat()); // error
foo.add(new Animal()); // even if we make animal non-abstract, error
```

There is in fact --not a single thing-- you could possibly put in the parentheses after `add` that the compiler will compile. Except for the useless academic case of `foo.add(null);` (literally, `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`, not 'some variable whose value happens to be `null`', no, the null literal typed directly into your source code), and that's only because the null literal is every type all at the same time.

However, this is fine for such a list:

```
Animal a = list.get(0);
```

That's because, if all I know is that this is a list that contains who knows, all I know is, it's restricted to only contain certain things, and that restriction is also unknown, but I do know it's Animal or some subtype of it. Then, therefore, the first element in it, is necessarily assignable to `Animal`.

As a mirror image, `List<? super Dog>` lets you add dogs, but `.get()` is useless (the expression `listOfSuperDog.get(0)` is of type `Object`, but, just like with `null`, that's academic: In java that list cannot contain non-objects, so `Object o = list.get(0);` is safe for all lists regardless of generics restrictions.

After all, if you want to express the idea of a *list of animals*, we already have that in java. That's simply `List<Animal>`. Not `List<? extends Animal>`. All dogs are animals, so, you can *of course* add a dog to a list of animals. Try it:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add(new Dog()); // fine
animals.add(new Cat()); // fine
```

`List<Animal>` is powerful in that you can add stuff to it, *and* meaningfully get things from it, but it is incredibly restricted in that only literally `List<Animal>` will do. `List<Cat>` won't (you can't pass a variable of type `List<Cat>`  to a method whose first arg is `List<Animal>`. After all, you can add a dog to a `List<Animal>`, and now there's a dog amongst your cats, that's no good). In contrast, `List<? extends Animal>` is far less powerful: You can only get from it, you can't add anything. But, on the plus side, you **can** pass a `List to it. Given that you can't add anything to it, it's fine. There is no risk that this results in a dog amongst your cats.

### So why doesn't my code make sense?

Generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination. If it doesn't result in compile-time stuff (the compiler inserting some casts for you or giving you warnings or errors), **they cannot possibly do anything**. The runtime doesn't know what they are, doesn't verify them, care about them, or in any way care about it whatsoever. Hence, if a generics variable shows up only once, **it is useless** - it serves to link things and how can it link things if it is only used once ever? You're either writing broken code or using generics for some weird hackery. Both are probably bad.

Here's a trivial example of how generics link things:

```
public <T> T nullOr(T left, T right) {
  return left == null ? right : left;
```

The generics link things: It says: Hey, caller? You can pick whatever type you want when you call me. I'm just telling you: The type of the first arg, the second arg, and the return type are **linked**. They are the same for any given call to `nullOr`. And the compiler ensures that your code makes sense and adheres to this linkage you've set up.

Your:

```
abstract <T extends Animal> T createFromList(List<Object> cells);
```

Is therefore just utterly broken:

1. It declares a typevar and uses it once. Insta red flag.
2. Every caller gets to pick a value for T. One caller thinks its Cat. Another thinks its Dog. Any `createFromList` implementation has no idea what it is (given that they are a figment of the compiler's imagination, there is no way to ask at runtime what type it is), and therefore **it is not possible to write a non-broken implementation of this method, period**<sup>1</sup>.

### Answer my questions then!

In your first case:

```
@Override Dog createFromList(Object cells) {}
```

The compiler can 'make it work' by moving to 'raw' mode. raw mode for `javac` is an all or nothing deal. If some signature, override, or expression involves raw code, then **all of it** turns raw. There is no picking and choosing.

Ordinarily you trivially get raw mode when you fail to add `<>` where they are ordinarily required. However, this is an exotic case where you also get raw mode.

### Huh? Why is this raw?

Let's first go with: What if it **is not** raw. The compiler has to ensure your code works *for all possible choices*. And it doesn't. After all, if the caller chooses `Cat`, well, a Dog is no Cat, so your method simply fails at a fundamental level (i.e. it wouldn't compile in the first place). `Dog foo()` cannot possibly be an override of `Cat foo()`, and yet, `Cat` is a possible choice you have to cater to. You don't, so this **cannot** be normal mode.

In raw mode, however, *it does work*. In raw mode, **all generics** revert to their lower bound. Which, here, is Animal. And you can 'tighten the return type'. If you have an abstract method that requires that all impls return an `Animal`, then having an impl that only returns Cat is fine. Cats are animals, after all. The key difference is, going back to the 'context' lesson up top, that `<? extends Animal>` doesn't mean 'Animal or any subtype of it'. It means: "I do not know. Could be Cat. Could be Dog". Key part of that sentence is: **Could be Cat**. Returning 'Dog' when your supermethod asks that you return 'Animal' is fine. Returning 'Dog' when your supermethod asks that you return 'Cat' **is not**.

### Now explain my compiler error

Looking at `AbstractClass`:

```
// what you wrote:
<T extends Animal> T createCells(List<Object> object);

// the raw mode version of that signature:
Animal createCells(List object);
```

I mentioned raw mode is an all or nothing deal. Thus, **all of it** becomes raw. Notably including the `List` parameter!

In order to have `Dog` work as the return type, javac has to switch to raw type. Which it can, but that means `List` is also raw, and `List<Object>` isn't, per the JLS, compatible with raw list when showing up in your signature like this.

This also explains why `@Override Dog createFromList(List /* raw */ cells) {}` **does** work.

### Do not ignore compiler warnings

Forget about your trials and tribulations with the compiler errors for a moment. Let's just look at `AbstractClass`. I can write this:

```
AbstractClass ac = whoKnowsHowIGetOne();
Cat cat = ac.createFromCells("hello");
```

and javac compiles it fine. After all, it's *the caller* that gets to pick generics bounds and this code totally makes sense if we pick 'Cat'. So `javac` picks that. However, your actual impl returns Dog. Java makes `ac.createFromCells("hello")` work here by silently injecting an invisible cast. Which means when I call your Dog-returning version, I get a ClassCastException. On a line that... has zero casts on it. Oof, that's confusing.

This gets us back to: There is no point to the `createFromCells` method. Either one. It's not possible.

### What you possibly meant

Perhaps you meant to write this:

```
class AbstractClass<T extends Animal> {
  abstract T createFromCells(Object obj);
  abstract T createFromCells(List<Object> list);
}
```

Now the generics aren't useless. The declared T is now actually used in *3* places: The constructor of `AbstractClass` (constructors silently inherit all type-level declared type vars), the return type of one method, and the return type of a second method. You can now write, without any generics warnings at all:

```
class DogMaker extends AbstractClass<Dog> {
  @Override public Dog createFromCells(Object obj) { .. }
  @Override public Dog createFromCells(List<Object> obj) { .. }
}
```

No warnings. No compiler errors. All works great.

---

[1] Non-hacky situations where 'declare type var, use it only once' is valid is when the return type is never going to matter at runtime. For example, a method that *always* throws (it cannot ever 'return normally' with a `return;` statement). Or one that always returns literally `null`. Having such a method is borderline hacky in the first place (why does it declare that it returns a value of type `Foo` when the method cannot actually ever normally return?). Hence, the simple rule of thumb remains: "Typevars declared and used exactly once are a red flag".

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was very useful esp. the "Huh? Why is this raw?" and "Now explain my compiler error" :-)  Understanding these compiler tricks and the "raw mode" is more than simply understanding the "PECS" principle. The sample code that I gave is indeed a reworked and simplified version of a homework thus it was interesting to understand the specific compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you add a type parameter () to the overridden method, it changes the method's signature enough to avoid the clash with the original method in the superclass, even if the return type is Dog.

I hope that helpful for you.